# Android: How to convert string"R.string.aButton" into resource R.string.aButton?

Tags: java, android, string

So here i have example code:

```
TextView aDisplayw=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);

protected void set(String resource) {
   String toResource = "R.string" + resource;//How to convert it into resource?
   aDisplay.setText(getResources().getText(forString));
}
```

So is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried [Java reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Please forget the code and "converting" (you can't convert one integer into another) and instead, describe in the easiest way you can, what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh, dont understand that, could you show me an example

Comment: yeah, maybe because my english is quite weak...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Resources.getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(
    resource, // Name
    "string", // Type
    getPackageName());
aDisplay.setText(resourceId);
```

Comment: Note that this is slow and isn't recommended. Granted, there are definitely times when you don't have a choice. However, if you can, it's best to avoid this method.

Comment: @JamesMcMurray - you're totally right, although there isn't much of an alternative if all you have is a the name of a resource. Ideally, you'd just want to avoid this situation entirely.